# Linux using Python 2 instead of 3

Tags: python, django, linux

I recently installed linux minut on my laptop and am curretley trying to learn databases with django and python. My issue is that Linux seems to be using python 2 instead of python 3. So when pip installing django it installs the 1.11 version instead of the 2.0.

I think it has something to do with this error message

```
The directory '/home/zac/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not 
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check 
the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with 
sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Comment: You should use `python3` instead of `python` as well as `pip3` instead of `pip` for Python-3.x. It is probably installed.

Comment: I tried doing a bash alias for python = python3 earlier. pip3 install django still resulted in the error above.

Comment: Just to add that `pip3` is sometimes not installed for distributions, so you can `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: Actually when I  enter $ pip3 install Django==2.0.6       I get                                                                              
 Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytz'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Also, there is an install guide for ubuntu that i'm guessing will work for you as well: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-django-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @SockMonkey: you probably should use `sudo` here, since it installs the packages globally (in the system directory `/usr`), so `sudo pip3 install Djang==2.0.6`. Nevertheless you better use a virtual environment when you install packages, since then you do not need `sudo`, and since packages can be unsafe, the security risk is smaller.

Comment: What Linux distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Django2** is only supported by python3, **Django-1.11.x was the last version of Django supported by python2**. To use django2 you need it to use using python3.

> I **strongly recommend** using virtual environment for all django development.

You can follow this process:

**Install pip3**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Install Virtual Environment for Python3**

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

**Create a project directory**

```
mkdir ~/newproject
cd ~/newproject
```

**Create a new virtual environment and activate it**

In this environment `pip` by default is `pip3` and `python` by default is `python3`.

```
virtualenv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

**Now Install Django**

```
pip install django
```

and then **create project and start** it,

```
django-admin startproject my_project

cd my_project

python manage.py runserver
```

It should work this way.